# Set Redirect UrlAfter Login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have Blazor Server hooked up with Azure B2C Cookie Auth.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.CookieScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

        services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(
            AzureADB2CDefaults.CookieScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieName";
            });
```

I'm mapping Controllers so I have Controller Endpoints to hit:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
```

In my Blazor Server `_Host` I simply am using the built in `Authorize` attirbute:

```
@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]
```

On load, if the user isn't Authorized, it will redirect to B2C Sign in without issue. I can then sign in and it directs me back to the App.

However, what I can't figure out is after login how to redirect to a **specific** controller/action endpoint prior something like: `/api/auth/mynewuser` This action would then do some verification and redirect back to "/" allowing the user to continue using the Blazor app.

Given my out of the box setup pretty much... how to achieve this?

***edit***

Code:

https://github.com/aherrick/BlazorServerB2C

Goal is to hit this endpoint after every login/sign up:

https://github.com/aherrick/BlazorServerB2C/blob/master/BlazorServerB2C/Controllers/AuthorizeController.cs

Answer (score 1):

When you sign in using Azure AD B2C, the B2C service sends a token to the "redirect_uri" .You can mention the Redirect URL used in the authentication [route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to a specific controller/action endpoint dynamically. This helps the app to redirect to the controller when authentication is successful.

Also, You can easily handle user is logged in or not by implementing [AuthorizeView component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authorizeview-component) or [[Authorize] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#authorize-attribute).

I looked into your code Authorizationcontroller and the newuser action which is under construction.
If you can trigger on the razor page, you can use the following:

```
@page "/YourPageName"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>xxx</h1>
.
.
.


@code {

    void MethodToTriggerUrl()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("PageToRedirect");
    }
}
```

Also, please refer [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: When you said it sends a "token" to the "redirect_url" are you talking about the /signin-oidc ? Is there some example code that shows how this works and how to deal with the token?

Comment: @aherrick Yes,  Oauth2.0 and oidc. Please go through an [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) developed for  Xamarin Forms in [MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations). You can also implement it directly without MSAL using few get and post operations directly with [Oauth2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure this really helps me. Really trying to understand this in the context of ASP.Net or Blazor. I just simply need to understand how to redirect to an endpoint once logged in or registered.

Comment: @aherrick,  If you make the redirect URL as equal to the endpoint then when the user logged in will automatically redirect to the endpoint page. If the user is unauthorized, then it can be handled on the page by the above components mentioned or an if loop in page load which checks for authorization and send the user to the login page.

Comment: which redirect URL? are you talking about the "CallbackPath" from appsettings? I've tried to set it to "api/Authorize/NewUser" and it doesn't hit that endpoint after login in the example code shown above.

Comment: @aherrick, I understood you are facing issues with redirection. I will research and get back to you

Comment: my goal is not to hit the razor page then redirect. i want B2C to automatically direct me to the endpoint i desire.

Comment: @aherrick, Are you trying to specify any filters between redirect_url and the Action?